# Rails 4 using Carmen gem cannot convert country name in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carmen

i am using the carmen gem to store the country as their country code like for United states it is US . but when i retrieve the country in the view i retrieve it as their full name

i have a model user and account

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :account
    end

 class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :User
    end
```

and

```
 @users = User.includes(:admin, :account).
       where.not(admin: { role: 'SUPER' }).where("names like ? OR accounts.country like ?" , "%#{ search }%", "%#{ search }%")

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.names %>
  <%= Carmen::Country.coded(user.account.country).name %>
<% end %>
```

i have a user query which i have used in the view to find user names with their country but in the search like if i write US it gives me all the names of with country United states 
but i dont want to search the name with their country code , i want to write the whole country name

i know the issue is in the search query. the country code is stored in the database, so it is searching by the code , but i cant find out how to use carmen country code to their name conversion in the search query
Please help , thankx in advance

Comment: Not sure what your problem is here. Can you restate the question or provide an example of what is happening now and what you want to happen?

Comment: @sshaw i am getting the Country short forms from accounts.country such as "US", "UK", "IN"  and in search i want to write the full country name like "United States" so in where query i want to get full country name from the table

Comment: I still think I'm missing something. Why doesn't this (no error handling) work? `User.where('accounts.country like ?', "%#{Carmen::Country.coded(country).name}%")`

Answer (score 0):

You can get **Carmen Country object** using fuzzy matching (actually use Regular Expression) by passing extra option `fuzzy: true` that is default false to `Carmen::Country.named()` method.

```
country = Carmen::Country.named('bang')
```

return `nil` but

```
  country = Carmen::Country.named('bang', fuzzy: true)
```

return `<#Carmen::Country name="Bangladesh">`. Now you can get country 2 alpha code using `country.alpha_2_code` that return `"BD"` similarly alpha 3 code using `country.alpha_3_code` that you can use to you query.

**N.B:** Since here use fuzzy it will not give always right answer( I think most of the case :)) unless search key is close to actual word.

If I search `Carmen::Country.named('ban', fuzzy: true)` it return `<#Carmen::Country name="Albania">` though I was expecting `<#Carmen::Country name="Bangladesh">`.

You can find about `fuzzy` in `lib/carmen/querying.rb`( my carmen version is 1.0.2). I think it may help someone.

**Edited** Though it's not best answer, you can save actual name to another column named like `country_name` which value will be set using `after_save` rails call back.
Be careful about calling any active record update method with in callback  that call callback method may cause infinite loop. You can use `update_column` that does not call callback.

Comment: doesnt work , i wanted to find US by giving united states as input 
but it gave UM in the case of United states 
UM is United states Minor Outlying Islands